# Speaking computer science in mathematicalese

Tags: computer-science, math

I am in the process of writing a fairly long monograph on a computer science topic. However, I usually find myself in a position of having to write some computer science concept in mathematical terms, and it is difficult to me. For instance, say I want to write a for-loop or a void function. I do most of the time go to my Knuth or Cormen or Sedgewick, but they are not enough now. Is there a "manual" or some text I can take as example to translate computer science into mathematics?

### Edit

Let me be more specific (thanks, Uri). What I mean is: For example, I have a function that is void, and it returns a random string of length n. This caused my curiosity, I don't even know how to represent  void function in in math... but again, this is just an example.

Comment: Hate to say it, but those three are probably the most mathematical CS books out there.  If you're exhausting those, I think you might have to be a pioneer in this topic. :)

Comment: @sheep: :) I wish I were... I think I'm just working on a topic more applied than, say, pure permutation, or linked lists, and a fair bit more on probability theory, which those books don't touch at all.

Comment: Maybe I could help you offline if you sent me a manuscript and specific questions.  I was a math prof before I went into software development. http://www.johndcook.com/contact.html

Comment: As far as a random string of length n, you could simply say "X is a random string of length n...", and then be explicit about what you mean by "random". For example, is it chosen uniformly at random from all n-letter strings from some alphabet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summation or product notation can probably replace some for-loops.  Others can probably be expressed as logical quantifiers ("There exists i such that a[i] has some property"
or "a[i] has some property for all i").  (Sorry I don't know how to render these 
in Markdown...hope you get the idea.)

"Void functions"...hmmm, maybe some convenient logical notation to state preconditions 
and postconditions, since such functions are only useful for their side effects?

But I think most mathematicians will be familiar enough with descriptions of algorithms to understand any halfway reasonable pseudocode convention. Just try to stay away from
anything that requires a "language-lawyer" skill level in some particular programming 
language.

Comment: :) "Language-lawyer", I liked that. By the way, I tried the summation for for-loops, and a mathematician almost killed me while saying "yes, yes, but you're not adding anything here!"...

Comment: @Dervin: Well, there ya go...don't overthink this!  Be clear and concise, try to learn and abide by any topic-specific conventions, and mathematicians (and even normal people!) will be grateful for it.

Comment: +1 Received the same comment from a mathematician when I tried to use summation and product notation as a replacement for For loops.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to be more specific. Are you talking about translating algorithms? Writing code as pseudocode?

There are many more "mathematical" formalisms, many of them are used in formal verification of programs.
They are usually based on discrete mathematics.

Depending on what you're trying to do, Hoare Logic is a good way of representing the steps of algorithms, IMHO.

You could also formally specify some architectures and protocols using the [Z notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_notation).

Comment: Every formal notation of a construct I've seen has been in some form of discrete mathematics - mathematical logic, set theory, combinatorics, and algebra usually. Formal specification languages, like Z, are heavily based on the constructs from discrete mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

To address your specific question: in mathematics, if it takes no arguments and returns a random string of length n, it probably isn't a function at all!  That is, if f() is not equal to f() (e.g., with f() = rand()) then by definition f() isn't a function.  You can solve this in different ways, depending on your preferences: you could pass it the state parameter and have it return the modified state parameter, or you could make it a multivalued function and return all possible values, or you could use two functions: f(n, state) gives the next random string of length n while g(n, state) gives the new state after generating f(n, state).

Answer (score 1):

You could look into [Elements of Programming](http://www.elementsofprogramming.com/book.html) by Alexander Stepanov and Paul McJones :

> This book applies the deductive method
>   to programming by affiliating programs
>   with the abstract mathematical
>   theories that enable them to work.
>   Specification of these theories,
>   algorithms written in terms of these
>   theories, and theorems and lemmas
>   describing their properties are
>   presented together. The implementation
>   of the algorithms in a real
>   programming language is central to the
>   book. While the specifications, which
>   are addressed to human beings, should,
>   and even must, combine rigor with
>   appropriate informality, the code,
>   which is addressed to the computer,
>   must be absolutely precise even while
>   being general.

Comment: I like this book but most of the actual algorithms etc. are expressed in a dialect of C++, with "mathematical" notation reserved for defining concepts and properties (and even then they break out often into fragments of C++). It would not serve well I think as an example of how to express programs in mathematical notation, the programs in this book use C++, not even pseudo code.

Comment: Yes, that should be a big disclaimer. Nevertheless, I think the mapping between mathematical concepts and a real programming language constructs could be useful for the OP.